# Equation numbering inside aligned placed next to an alignedat

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, subequations

I have a group of equations on the left hand side and a group of explanations on the right hand side. Since the number of lines in both group differ from each other I use the `aligned` and `alignedat` for automatic alignment.

How do I get equation numbers for `f_1` and `f_2`? There are a lot of similar questions like this on stackexchange, but the answers boil down to use another environment like `align` or `split`. This is not feasible in my case, since I would lose the automatic alignment.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}[c]
    f_1 &= a + b\\ %1.1 here
    f_2 &= a - b\\ %1.2 here
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
    a &= &&\text{ Some one line text}\\
    b &= &&\text{ Some two line text}\\
    &&&\text{ 2nd line}\\
    \end{alignedat}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: How it should look]

Additionally it would be nice if I could freely decide if the numbers would be place left, middle (like in the picture) or right of the equation.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Valid placement specifier options for an `aligned` environment are `[t]` ("top"), `[c]` (centered -- the default), and `[b]` ("bottom"). `[r]` is *not* a valid option and is simply ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is the best way to set the display.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,varwidth}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}% <--- adjust to the needed width
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{flalign}
f_1 &= a + b &\\
f_2 &= a - b &
\end{flalign}
\end{minipage}
\qquad
$\begin{aligned}
a &= \text{Some one line text}\\
b &= \begin{varwidth}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
     Some two line text\\
     second line
     \end{varwidth}
\end{aligned}$
\end{center}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth} % choose a suitable width
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
\begin{align}
    f_1 &= a + b\\ %1.1 here
    f_2 &= a - b   %1.2 here
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{2cm} % or whatever spacing amount is desired
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
$\begin{aligned}
    a &= \text{A first line of text}\\
    b &= \text{A second line of text}\\
      &\quad \text{ And a third line}
 \end{aligned}$
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the minipage idea! But I'll go with egreg, because the without the second minipage, I get automatic horizontal alignment between the equations and the text.